# Sound identifier software

Tags: audio

I have roughly a minute long audio file, halfway through the recording there's a very distinct sound of something in the background, like a drawer closing, or an axe hitting a piece of wood.

Basically what I'm looking for is some software or online service where I can input this 10 second clip and it will identify exactly what it is, or what it could be, a list of 20 suggestions to go through would also be fine.

The only site I have been able to find so far are for identifying music.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is extremely difficult and interesting research topic. For example, see the [DCASE](http://dcase.community/) challenge. Google had been working hard on using their AudioSet in order to create a generic sound recogniser. Also, there are some companies out there, doing Sound Recognition for various applications, however, these are not generic products that you can use.

Your best shot is to use a system that is able to learn the sound based on a few samples. The only one I am aware of is described in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RyeH1MUEU6M), and you can use it [here](http://www1.arche.blue/sound-detector).